# Web service exception: " An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing java.lang.Exception: Host is not set"

Tags: java, web-services, maven, payara

I have a web method which gets some name and returns its required input type(BOM, AML, BOM and AML or any other name) by reading a class file(maven plugin file). While trying to do this, i am getting below exception.

```
[2017-08-02T17:14:33.902+0800] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-CORE-00037] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1501665273902] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
java.lang.Exception: Host is not set
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.util.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
]]
```

Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: This is reoccuring on one of my Production server from last couple of weeks , answer below is no use to me. Any one else getting this ?

Answer (score 0):

Again i build the war file by creating a new workspace(checkout from svn) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Grizzly obtains virtual host name from `Host` header in the request. Since HTTP 1.1, `Host` header is required. But if `Host` header is set an empty name, Grizzly cannot obtains the name and throws such exception.

Usually, `Host` request header is set by HTTP client. But even if `Host` header exists but its value is an empty because of some reasons, you will happen such a error.